# Clear duplicate rows in table

Tags: mysql

I have a table that I want to clear the duplicate rows in it according to 5 fields. Those fields are `origin_id`, `destination_id`,`market_id`,`cabin`,`tripType`.
What i want to do is, remove all the records that have same 5 fields except the one record that has the biggest `created_at`. I want to have only one record for each 5 fields.
After i clear the duplicates i will create a unique index but for now i cant do it because of the duplicates.

What i have so far is this query but it doesnt seem to be working:

```
DELETE FROM fares WHERE id NOT IN(
     SELECT f1.id FROM (SELECT * FROM fares) AS f1
     INNER JOIN (
          SELECT origin_id,destination_id,market_id,cabin,tripType,MAX(created_at) AS maxDate FROM fares
          GROUP BY origin_id,destination_id,market_id,cabin,tripType
     ) AS f2 ON f2.origin_id=f1.origin_id AND f2.destination_id=f1.destination_id AND 
     f2.market_id=f1.market_id AND f2.cabin=f1.cabin AND f2.tripType=f1.tripType
     WHERE f1.created_at=f2.maxDate
     GROUP BY f1.origin_id,f1.destination_id,f1.market_id,f1.cabin,f1.tripType
)
```

The query above only deletes 500 rows but i have 8k duplicates. Which i capture with the following query.

```
SELECT SUM(f.numberOfFares) AS duplicateFares FROM (
    SELECT origin_id,destination_id,market_id,cabin,tripType,COUNT(1) AS numberOfFares FROM fares
    GROUP BY origin_id,destination_id,market_id,cabin,tripType
    HAVING count(1)>1
) AS f
```

[Query above results this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqVRW.png)

I want to have 1 record for per `origin_id`,`destination_id`,`market_id`,`cabin`,`tripType` group

I guess problem is the records that have same created_at value

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14ec8d/1/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for is called 'deduplicate'. Basically you compare by joining the table to itself and delete the ones you don't want:

```
delete F2
from Fares F1
join Fares F2 on F1.origin_id = F2.origin_id 
    and F1.destination_id = F2.destination_id 
    and F1.market_id = F2.market_id 
    and F1.cabin = F2.cabin 
    and F1.tripType = F2.tripType 
where F2.created_at = F1.created_at
```

Having indexes on the columns you are comparing on will speed things up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering what would be the output if 2 individual records have the same created_at value. Because they do in my situation

Comment: Added an example sqlfiddle

Comment: If there are more than one row with the same created_at value, then add a test on another field to decide which to keep, such as an auto_increment column for example.